# Putting JPanels with colored borders in a specific order so they look like a grid

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I'm trying to code a grid with bordercolored JPanels on a "bigger" JPanel.
I don't know how to put these Panels in the right size and order to look like a grid. After this i want to put in an Action Listener for the Button so it places an an obeject on a specific Panel on the grid, but right now this is not my Problem. I hope you understand what I mean and can help me. Thanks

```
package feld;

import javax.swing.*;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;


public class Spielplan {
public static void main(String[] args) {

JFrame f1 = new JFrame();
f1.setSize(600,600);
    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
JButton tokens = new JButton("Spielsteine setzen");
p1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
p1.add(tokens, BorderLayout.NORTH);
f1.setVisible(true);
f1.add(p1);

JPanel g1 = new JPanel();
g1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
g1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
g1.setVisible(true);
p1.add(g1);

JPanel g2 = new JPanel();
g2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
g2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
g2.setVisible(true);
p1.add(g2);

JPanel g3 = new JPanel();
g3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
g3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
g3.setVisible(true);
p1.add(g3);

JPanel g4 = new JPanel();
g4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
g4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
g4.setVisible(true);
p1.add(g4);

JPanel g5 = new JPanel();
g5.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
g5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
g5.setVisible(true);
p1.add(g5);

JPanel g6 = new JPanel();
g6.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
g6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
g6.setVisible(true);
p1.add(g6);

JPanel g7 = new JPanel();
g7.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
g7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
g7.setVisible(true);
p1.add(g7);

JPanel g8 = new JPanel();
g8.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
g8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
g8.setVisible(true);
p1.add(g8);

JPanel g9 = new JPanel();
g9.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
g9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
g9.setVisible(true);
p1.add(g9);
}
}
```

Comment: You could use a grid layout which places everything... well in a grid.

Comment: Something like: `p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3))`

Comment: But then my Button would be part of this grid wouldnt it ? and i need it outside the grid.

Comment: Do you mean something [like this for example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292400/drawing-a-gridline-in-the-same-part-where-i-created-the-jpanel/29292521#29292521)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

You should assign BorderLayout to the JFrame. Then assign the JButton to the NORTH position of the JFrame, and the JPanel to the CENTER position. Remember to use `.pack()` on a JFrame to make sure the elements are fitted properly. Lastly, remember a default closing method, I provided one here `.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);`.

The actual grid is provided by setting the panels Layout to GridLayout. Hope this helps you.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Spielplan {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    JFrame f1 = new JFrame();
    f1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    f1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(960, 800));

    JButton tokens = new JButton("Spielsteine setzen");
    f1.add(tokens, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
    p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    f1.add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    JPanel g1 = new JPanel();
    g1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    g1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    g1.setVisible(true);
    p1.add(g1);

    JPanel g2 = new JPanel();
    g2.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    g2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    g2.setVisible(true);
    p1.add(g2);

    JPanel g3 = new JPanel();
    g3.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    g3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    g3.setVisible(true);
    p1.add(g3);

    JPanel g4 = new JPanel();
    g4.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    g4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    g4.setVisible(true);
    p1.add(g4);

    JPanel g5 = new JPanel();
    g5.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    g5.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    g5.setVisible(true);
    p1.add(g5);

    JPanel g6 = new JPanel();
    g6.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    g6.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    g6.setVisible(true);
    p1.add(g6);

    JPanel g7 = new JPanel();
    g7.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    g7.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    g7.setVisible(true);
    p1.add(g7);

    JPanel g8 = new JPanel();
    g8.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    g8.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    g8.setVisible(true);
    p1.add(g8);

    JPanel g9 = new JPanel();
    g9.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.RED));
    g9.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    g9.setVisible(true);
    p1.add(g9);

    f1.pack();
    f1.setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Comment: Yes, thanks it helped me a lot. is there a way to put these panels together so I dont have to write them 1 by 1 ? Sorry im pretty new to coding i dont know how to express better. I hope you understand what i mean

Answer (score 2):

Try using a GridLayout and adding your Panels to it.
Something like:

```
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3,3));
```

If you want to to still use your button on the top create a panel for the whole screen with the BorderLayout as you did. Then add the Button to NORTH and another JPanel using the GridLayout to the CENTER. Place your JPanels with the colored Borders in the JPanel with the GridLayout.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot. My problem was not as hard as i thought and i don't really know why i  havnt thought about using just a gridlayout for my Panels.