# Java Swing - Making Transparent JButtons, Opaque borders

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton, jlabel

I have a JFrame, and within it, a JLabel that is filled by an image of a Map. I want to have clickable square “Tiles” in a grid over the image of the map. To do this, I made a large grid of JButtons that I have added to the JLabel containing the Map. However, the Map cannot be seen, so I have made the JButtons completely transparent. However, when they are Transparent, I can’t see where one JButton ends, and where another one starts. I want to create a JButton that is totally transparent on the inside, but still has a visible border around it. I have tried `setOpaque(false)` and then `setBorderPainted(true)` but that makes them opaque again. I have tried everything I could find, but nothing happens. Any suggestions?

Once again, all I want is a Transparent JButton with Visible Borders

Comment: Have you tried adding a `Border` to the `JButton`? Have a look at [How to Use Borders](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more details

Comment: Maybe [edit] your question and post your code. Not all of it, just a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to replace border with you own...

[image: Border Button]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setBackground(Color.RED);
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            JButton btn = new JButton("Hello");
            btn.setOpaque(false);
            btn.setContentAreaFilled(false);
            btn.setBorderPainted(true);

            btn.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.BLUE));

            add(btn);

        }

    }
}
```

You might need to use a `CompoundBorder` with a `EmptyBorder` on the inside to provide some padding (I tried using `setMargins` but it didn't seem to work)

Comment: Thanks so much, it worked like a charm, except for one problem. You gave a perfect answer, but now, the border is too large. You see, the map is 1200 by 600 pixels, and the Grid of Buttons contains 5000 buttons. When the LineBorder is active, the line thickness is too large even when the thickness parameter is 1. Is there any possible way to make the line thickness 1 pixel?

Comment: What you're seeing is the fact that each button has a 1 pixel border, so when it butts up against another button, it will appear as 2 pixels (1 pixel for each button).  You might need to use a `MatteBorder` instead

Comment: @Notalexander Sorry, had to go dig out [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292400/drawing-a-gridline-in-the-same-part-where-i-created-the-jpanel/29292521#29292521)

Comment: I used your suggestion and made the MatteBorder with only the bottom and right sides drawn in and it looks perfect. The tiles don’t have to be pixel perfect, so it works fine and looks great. Thanks for all the help I really appreciate it